# How do I add to a variable, then loop back to 0 once a maximum value is achived?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add `x` to `value`, however when the `value` is equal to `max_value`, it much wrap back to zero and continue adding the rest of `x`.
For example,

```
x = 5
value = 6
max_value = 8
```

This should return `value = 3`

So far I have

```
value += x
    if value >= max_value:
        value = value - max_value
```

However this only works for when `value + x` is less than `2 * max_value`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is modular arithmetic.

You can use the modulo operator `%` in Python to achieve this. E.g.

```
x = 5
value = 6
max_value = 8

value = (value + x) % max_value
```

The modulo operator (`%`) returns the remainder of the integer division of the left side by the right side. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) for details.

Comment: Does this work on bigger numbers (and a greater range between them)

Comment: This should work on any integer, and perhaps even floats

Comment: @OlvinRoght can you explain a little more? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: if you change the max_value to 12 then surely the expected output would be 4 but your program gives 11

Comment: I'd like to add that this will make `value` equal to `0` when `(value + x) = max_value`. In other words, this will always give you a value between `0` and `max_value - 1`. If you instead want it between `1` and `max_value` you could use `value = ((value + x - 1) % max_value) + 1`

Comment: @thehumaneraser yes that is right. I interpret "however when the value is equal to max_value, it much wrap back to zero and continue adding the rest of x. " as saying value should be between `0` and `max_value - 1`

Comment: @malthuseater you are welcome, kindly select this answer as the accepted one, if it solved your problem

Comment: @Evorage, since 0 <= value < max_value , 11 is the correct output

Comment: @L.Grozinger I wanted the value to go to 0 when value == max_value, so this works